# Pointing google cloud endpoints iOS client at development server

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

After deploying google cloud endpoints on my local development server, and generating the iOS client library using the steps outlined here :

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios

I am trying to point the iOS client at my development server. I tried changing the `self.rpcURL` in `GTLMyApi.h` to my local development URL as follows :

```
self.rpcURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://x.x.x.x:8080/_ah_api/rpc?prettyPrint=false"];
```

from the original value of :

```
self.rpcURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myapi.appspot.com/_ah/api/rpc?prettyPrint=false"]
```

but that throws the exception :

```
Insecure fetch request has a scheme (http) not found in fetcher allowInsecureSchemes...
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use SSL. Can you change your development server to use `https`? Have you tried just setting the URL to `https://x.x.x.x:8080/...` Another solution may be to try using `http://x.x.x.x:80/` as port 8080 may be expect SSL connection.

Comment: I get the following when I change it to https : CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9847) and NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9847)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to allow HTTP with:

```
service.fetcherService.allowedInsecureSchemes = @[ @"http" ];
```

In your case it may be self instead of service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting as follows in iOS app the rpcURL:

```
self.rpcURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/rpc?prettyPrint=false"];
#if DEBUG
self.fetcherService.allowedInsecureSchemes = @[@"http"];
self.allowInsecureQueries = YES;
self.fetcherService.allowLocalhostRequest = YES;
self.rpcURL = [NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.2:8888/_ah/api/rpc?prettyPrint=false"];
#endif
```

And in GTMOAuth2Authentication.m in

```
- (BOOL)authorizeRequestImmediateArgs:(GTMOAuth2AuthorizationArgs *)args
```

right after:

```
BOOL isAuthorizableRequest = self.shouldAuthorizeAllRequests
|| [scheme caseInsensitiveCompare:@"https"] == NSOrderedSame
|| [requestURL isFileURL];
```

I've added in:

```
#if DEBUG
isAuthorizableRequest = self.shouldAuthorizeAllRequests
|| [scheme caseInsensitiveCompare:@"http"] == NSOrderedSame
|| [requestURL isFileURL];
#endif
```

Hope this helps.